# How to decrease or completely get rid of reCaptchas

Tags: captcha

Whenever I access a site on TOR browser, I encounter these reCaptchas that are very tedious, repetitive, and long.

I have Chrome open as well, I use a VPN, I've tried turning up and down the security level. Those were all solutions I've seen but never worked for me. Google throws like 100 puzzles at me to solve, and when I solve them correctly, Google tells me to try again and it's been driving me INSANE lately. How do I resolve this WITHOUT complicated things like Exit Nodes?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good/easy way of reducing these captchas when using Tor. Any solution would require another proxy after the Tor exit relay, but this is harmful to anonymity.

Comment: There's really no hope with Google. They strictly do not want Tor users because they can't make money off of them. When it comes to smaller websites, email them, explain why Tor is important and why they should allow Tor users and cross your fingers.